# Find an equation of a tangent line

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Find an equation of a the tangent line to the graph of $x^2 - xy - y^2= 1$ when $(x,y) = (2,1)$.

Here's what I have so far:

$$ x^2 - xy - y^2 = 1
$$

$$\implies x^2 - xy - y^2  - 1 = 0
$$

$$\implies y' = 2x - xy' - 2yy'
$$

$$\implies -2x = y'(-x -2y)
$$

By trying to simplify the equation so that $y'$ is on one side, is that the correct way to begin solving the problem in the first place? If so, is my simplification correct as shown above?

Comment: Yes, you want a formula for $y'$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Given $y'=\frac{2x-y}{x+2y}$ and $(x,y)=(2,1)$, what is the slope of the graph at $(2,1)$? How can you combine that information effectively with the point-slope form of a line?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I think I've solved my problem after finding the slope. Just to confirm, would the slope be $m= \frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: @LaylaA312 Yes. Then $y-1=\frac{3}{4}(x-2)$ and so on. Good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ x^2 - xy - y^2 = 1
$$

$$\implies x^2 - xy - y^2  - 1 = 0
$$

$$\implies y' = 2x - xy' - 2yy'
$$

$$\implies -2x = y'(-x -2y)
$$

Therefore, 
$$ y' = \frac{2x - y}{x+2y} $$

By using $x = 2$ and $y = 1$ from the point (2,1), plug the two values into $y$ to get the slope, $m$.

$$ y' = \frac{2(2) - (1)}{(2)+2(1)} $$
and
$$m =\frac{3}{4}$$

By using the point slope formula, you can find the equation of the tangent line to the given graph at the point (2,1)

$$y - y_1 = m (x- x_1) $$

$$y-1 =\frac{3}{4}(x-2)$$

$$y = \frac{3}{4}x - \frac{1}{2}$$